# Workflow foundation - multiple bookmarks

Tags: workflow-foundation

We have a state machine implemented as a windows workflow. The idea should be straight forward:

1. load workflow
2. preform activity
3. stop (wait for user to start next step)

Our team is learning WWF as we go. we found a bookmark can be creataed to pause and unload the workflow. The workflow can then be resumed by loading the workflow by ID and resuming the bookmark.

```
//start
var workflow = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkflow(), identity);
workflow.Run();
//run step 1, create bookmark in transition 1

//.....
//resume
var workflow = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkflow(), identity);
workflow.Load(id);
workflow.ResumeBookmark("step 2", obj);
//run step 2. finish
```

This part works. But now we want to introduce a third step. Transition 2 should create a new bookmark and then resume the workflow to run step 3.

```
//run step 3
var workflow = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkflow(), identity);
workflow.Load(id);
workflow.ResumeBookmark("step 3", obj);
//run step 3. finish
```

However this is not working as expected. The workflow is loaded, but resuming `step 3` bookmark doesn't execute the step 3 activity. It seems like either a workflow can only handle 1 bookmark, or the first bookmark in transition 1 is not cleared/removed after resuming with `step 2`.

I searched the internet but I haven't found enough information on this subject. There are plenty of examples of using a single bookmark in a workflow. But nothing on multiple bookmarks in a workflow.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also facing the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with StateMachine type and lot of bookmarks in WWF 4.5 without any problems. Our team have implemented helpdesk type of application, so bookmarks were placed in Action activities of Transitions. When workflow come to State, all Action activities of all transitions from State are triggered and bookmarks created. Resuming one of the bookmarks will clear all other bookmars and move StateMachine to another State, so new Transitions and bookmarks can be created.

Answer (score 0):

OKay, I found this and worked for me. 
[MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ca4044c-92b1-440f-bd27-6fef1e556e25/windows-workflow-bookmark-issue?forum=wfprerelease)

Assuming you are overriding  **CanInduceIdle** in all your bookmark creations, you just need to persist the workflow in the Idle. Add  below in your resumption code.

```
     application.PersistableIdle = e => PersistableIdleAction.Persist;
     application.PersistableIdle = e => PersistableIdleAction.Unload;
```